# How I can get push notification from server in cordova?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification, notifications

In my Cordova app iOS/Android my application will check if there is internet connection it will receive data from server(web service) and use notification

I tried plugin "katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications" but it will make notification local from my application not from server or web service or url

all examples i tried was like

```
cordova.plugins.notification.local.schedule({
    id: 1,
    title: "Production Jour fixe",
    text: "Duration 1h",
    firstAt: monday_9_am,
    every: "week",
    sound: "file://sounds/reminder.mp3",
    icon: "http://icons.com/?cal_id=1",
    data: { meetingId:"123#fg8" }
});

cordova.plugins.notification.local.on("click", function (notification) {
    joinMeeting(notification.data.meetingId);
});
```

I mean when user follow department in my application, he will receive all items and new about this department and newly in notification I need to know how I can do that?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is that there must be a thousand tutorials/examples that can be found by a simple Google search for cordova push notifications.

Comment: @Roope all  thousand tutorials/examples which i found in google are local from application not from server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a simple plugin to get notifications from server side to my cordova application. You can have a look at this plugin : [LINK](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push)

Hot to use?

> JavaScript

```
var push = PushNotification.init({
    android: {
        senderID: "12345679"
    },
    browser: {
        pushServiceURL: 'http://push.api.phonegap.com/v1/push'
    },
    ios: {
        alert: "true",
        badge: "true",
        sound: "true"
    },
    windows: {}
});

push.on('registration', function(data) {
    // data.registrationId
});

push.on('notification', function(data) {
    // data.message,
    // data.title,
    // data.count,
    // data.sound,
    // data.image,
    // data.additionalData
});

push.on('error', function(e) {
    // e.message
});
```

> Server (using C#)

```
public string SendGCMNotification(string apiKey, string deviceId, string postData)
{
    string postDataContentType = "application/json";
    apiKey = "AIzaSyC13...PhtPvBj1Blihv_J4"; // hardcorded
    deviceId = "da5azdfZ0hc:APA91bGM...t8uH"; // hardcorded

    string message = "Your text";
    string tickerText = "example test GCM";
    string contentTitle = "content title GCM";
    postData =
    "{ \"registration_ids\": [ \"" + deviceId + "\" ], " +
      "\"data\": {\"tickerText\":\"" + tickerText + "\", " +
                 "\"contentTitle\":\"" + contentTitle + "\", " +
                 "\"message\": \"" + message + "\"}}";


    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);

    //
    //  MESSAGE CONTENT
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

    //
    //  CREATE REQUEST
    HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
    Request.Method = "POST";
    Request.KeepAlive = false;
    Request.ContentType = postDataContentType;
    Request.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", apiKey));
    Request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

    Stream dataStream = Request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();

    //
    //  SEND MESSAGE
    try
    {
        WebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse();
        HttpStatusCode ResponseCode = ((HttpWebResponse)Response).StatusCode;
        if (ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized) || ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden))
        {
            var text = "Unauthorized - need new token";
        }
        else if (!ResponseCode.Equals(HttpStatusCode.OK))
        {
            var text = "Response from web service isn't OK";
        }

        StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream());
        string responseLine = Reader.ReadToEnd();
        Reader.Close();

        return responseLine;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
    return "error";
}

public static bool ValidateServerCertificate(
object sender,
X509Certificate certificate,
X509Chain chain,
SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
    return true;
}
```